# how to put data in fact table?

Tags: etl, business-intelligence, talend, star-schema

i'm new in business intelligence
and i design a star schema that implement a data mart to help analyst to take a decision about student grades
dimensions tables :
- module (module code, module name) that contains information about the module
- student ( code, first_name, last_name, ....) that contains information about the model
- school subject ( code, name, professor name...)
- degree ( code, libelle)
- specialite (code, libelle)
- time(year,half year)
- geographie(continent,country,city)
fact table :
- result ( score, module score, year score)
the data source is excel file :
in each file i have a set of sheet for each sheet he present a students score in "Niveau 'X' , Specialite 'Y', Year and Half-Year 'Z',Module 'U',City 'A'...
my question is :
how i can't put data from excel to my dimensions and fact
to dimensions i suppose that is easy but i need your proposition
to fact i have no idea

i'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: You've tagged etl. You need to pick an etl tool. This is sometimes dictated by the database you're building on which is.... what?

Comment: thank you for your response
the ETL that i use is TALEND Open Studio
and the data warehouse Implementation i use is ssas microsoft

Comment: when i fill my dimensions with data i will use talend and i give to talend the instruction to generate an auto-increment PK for each dimenssion but my problem is how to put the data (score, module_score, year_score) in fact table and the real problem how associate this values to dimensions (using FK-PK association)

Comment: A dimension table contains surrogate keys (auto incremented PK) but it also contains 'source keys' which you use to match back to the data you are importing. So your module dimension will actually contain the module code. When you load your fact you look up the module code and extract the surrogate key and write that to the fact. Make sure there is a unique constraint on the keys you are using to lookup

Comment: the dimensions FKs in fact table should be manually put or they exit a mechanism for to put it automatically thank for your help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but your first step is to load the dimensions, and the dimension rows (members) need to include data that allows you to match back to the data that loaded it. So do that first - load the dimensions. I don't know what tools talend has to help. Try a few things and ask specific questions

Answer (score 2):

Most basic answer, pick an ETL tool and start moving the data.
You will generally need to:

1. Load your dimension tables first. The ID columns  in these tables will link to the fact table.
2. In your ETL package/routine to populate the fact table,
3. select the data to be placed in the fact table from the source/staging.
4. do a lookup on each of the dimension tables against this data to get the ID of each Dimension value.
5. Finally do some duplicate detection to see if any of the rows are already in the fact table.
6. insert the data.

This process will be broadly similar regardless of the ETL tool you use. There are a few tutorials that go into some detail (use google) but the basic technique is lookups to get the dimension keys.

Comment: this is a really good answer when you are working strictly by the dimensional modeling rules. from my point of view I would go with using HKEYs instead of surrogate keys, to ingest in parallel as I am working with Snowflake which supports the insert all into many tables. is it a good thing or should i stick to the rules and just use surrogate keys?